# Unexpected inconsistency, root filesystem requires manual fsck, boots to (initramfs) on Lubuntu. Has been occuring frequently

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lubuntu

So, whenever I boot into Lubuntu, I sometimes get an error from the root filesystem that requires a manual fsck, and it boots to initramfs. I know how to solve the problem, but I've been getting this error more and more frequently on boot-up. I also noticed that every time I fix the issue, the number of orphaned files is increasing, and that's worrying me. I'm dual-booting Windows 10 Education and Lubuntu 18.04 Long-Term Support. Is there a reason as to why this error keeps happening?

Comment: Have you installed a Windows driver that allows you to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions? Exactly... what do you do to fix the problem now?

Comment: I run a manual fsck check, reboot the computer, and then Lubuntu works when I run it. I don't have any Windows drivers that allow me to read/write Linux ext2/3/4 partitions. Would that affect this error?

Comment: Yes, that Windows driver would be corrupting your Ubuntu installation, but you don't have it, so no worries. Next step... start the `Disks` app, select your hard disk, then go to the "hamburger" icon and select SMART Data & Tests. Edit your question with screenshot(s) of the SMART Data window, and we'll take a look at your disk health. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.